# Dúvida com a função compareTo

Tags: java

Quando eu executo o código abaixo o `compareTo` retorna um valor menor que zero.

```
public class compare
{
 public static void main ( String [] args )
 {
    String str1 = "araraaaaaa";  
    String str2 = "asa";  

    int comp = str1.compareTo(str2);  

    System.out.println(""+comp) //  printa -1 na tela

 }
}
```

Teoricamente, `str1` não é maior que `str2`?
Por que ele retorna negativo?

Comment: Se estiver querendo comparar o conteúdo dessas strings, use `str1.equals(str2);` que retorna 'true' se forem iguais.

Answer (score 7):

O método `compareTo` da classe `String` é utilizado para ordenar as `String`s alfabeticamente*, e não por tamanho. Desta forma temos que `"araraaaaaa"` vem antes de `"asa"`, e portanto o `compareTo` dá -1, porque ao comparar a primeira letra as duas `String`s são iguais (`a`) e ao comparar a segunda, o `r` vem antes do `s`.

Para comparar as `String`s por tamanho, você deveria invocar o método `length` das `String`s e então comparar os tamanhos diretamente. <sup><sub>(Sugestão do [Marcelo Bonifazio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/14262/marcelo-bonifazio))</sub></sup>

Vale lembrar também que sempre que temos `a.compareTo(b)` retornando -1 (ou algum outro número negativo) significa que `a` antecede `b`, se retorna +1 (ou algum outro número positivo) então `a` sucede `b` e se retorna 0 então `a` e `b` são similares. Entrentanto a definição exata de "antecede", "sucede" e "similar" fica a critério de cada classe que implementa o `compareTo`. No caso da classe `String` a definição é dada pela ordenação alfabética*.

---

(*) - Na verdade a comparação não é exatamente alfabética, e sim é baseada em comparação de sequências de valores numéricos de *codepoints* unicode.

Comment: uma alternativa seria nomeDaString.length();

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio Exato